# How to take a picture by looking to the display of the Nikon D5100 instead of looking through the viewfinder eyepiece?

Tags: nikon-d5100

I have a new Nikon D5100 camera. I find it difficult to take shots by looking to the scene using the viewfinder eyepiece.

Is it possible to take a picture or to film a video by watching the scene on the display (also known as monitor) of the camera instead of looking through viewfinder eyepiece?

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/at-what-point-should-we-cover-extremely-basic-information-trivial-to-find-in-the).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your D5100, "Live View" mode is activated by trigerring the 'Lv' switch next to the Mode selection dial (right under the 'Info' button).

[image: Nikon D5100 top view]

However, this information is covered in the [manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D5100_ENnoprint.pdf) of your camera. There you have it in page 99, section 'Live View'. If you are new to the camera, you should definitely go through it, it'll help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right, I am totally new to this camera and to photography in general. Actually, my girlfriend is the one with the question and I just wanted to find it out for her. We'll start reading the manual right away. Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't video always Live View, after all, the mirror is up for video.

Comment: @Robin I'm not sure what you mean. Is that a question? Mirror locks up in both cases so the camera can show you in the screen what the sensor is seeing. But Live View shows a real-time view and takes a photo, while Video mode, well... records video

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for is called "Live View". On this camera (and similar ones from Nikon), this is activated by a switch next to the mode dial on top of the camera.